# How to find id of a comment in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have code:

```
<a onclick="lel($(this),'212345555')" class="button">
<a onclick="lel($(this),'241214370')" class="button">
<a onclick="lel($(this),'248916550')" class="button">
<a onclick="lel($(this),'253234444')" class="button">
<a onclick="lel($(this),'248914570')" class="button">
```

And i want to execute all of this `lel($(this),'id')`in js at once, but i dont know how to get id of every button.

Comment: By saying ID's i mean these numbers '212345555'.

Comment: <a onclick="lel($(this),'212345555')" class="button"> it is a code to delete image on site, but there is lots of different images with diffrent id's and i want to delete all of them.

Comment: You should use checkbox to delete all or multiple images

Answer (score 0):

If u can manipulate server code to make like below

```
<a id="212345555" class="button">
<a id="241214370" class="button">
<a id="248916550" class="button">
<a id="253234444" class="button">
<a id="248914570" class="button">
```

and with jquery

```
$('a.button').click(function(){
  let($(this),this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the following HTML

```
<a onclick="lel($(this),'212345555')" class="button">
<a onclick="lel($(this),'241214370')" class="button">
<a onclick="lel($(this),'248916550')" class="button">
<a onclick="lel($(this),'253234444')" class="button">
<a onclick="lel($(this),'248914570')" class="button">
```

You can parse these identifiers using regular expressions and then run the lel operation on all of the parsed id's using the following Javascript

```
function gatherAndExecute() {
    // iterate through each a.button that defines an onclick attribute
    $('a.button[onclick]').each(function(i, e) {
        // retrieve the onclick attribute
        var rawId = e.attributes['onclick'].value;
        // parse the identifier out of the attribute
        var id = rawId.match(/lel\(\$\(this\),'(\d+)'\)/)[1];
        // call the lel function
        lel($(e), id);
    });
}
```

Please see this fiddle for a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/k9376p5c/

As a cleaner alternative, if you have the ability to change the HTML outputted by your server, adding an id attribute to these elements will avoid the extra work of parsing the identifier.